Clear ContentControl Content only VBA
in a word document, there are around 100 Content Controls (CC) with appropriate title and name. However, i want to clear contents of multiple CCs only, keeping the CC itself. Please note only the contents. The DELETE and CLEAR function remove the CC, thus can not keep the contents of the CC. The tag of CCs i want to clear contents are Section11, Section23, Section45, Section24, AppleID01. Below is what i wrote:
Sub ClearCCs_Contents()
  Dim CC As ContentControl
  For Each CC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
      CC.Range.Text = ""
  Next CC
End Sub

is that possible that i replace the "ActiveDocument.ContentControls" with a list of CC tags that i stated above? or is there any other direct simple approaches?
Main Issue: Creating a list of Content Controls using their tag/title name and run a loop to clear contents of CCs over items in the list.


Use Title or Tag property to identify the desired CC

Sub ClearCCs_Contents()
  Dim CC As ContentControl, i As Long, arrCC, c As Cell
  Const CC_LIST = "ab,Section11,Section23,Section45,Section24,AppleID01"
  arrCC = Split(UCase(CC_LIST), ",")
  For Each CC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    For i = LBound(arrCC) To UBound(arrCC)
        If UCase(CC.Title) = arrCC(i) Then
'        If UCase(CC.Tag) = arrCC(i) Then
            If CC.Range.Tables.Count > 0 Then
'                CC.Range.Tables(1).Delete ' delete table
                CC.Range.Tables(1).Range.Delete
            Else
                CC.Range.Text = ""
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
  Next CC
End Sub



how about if one of the CC is a table ( a table placed in a CC) while the rest is text type?

What's the expected output for the table in CC? Remove table or contents in table? I've updated the code.

The most efficient way to do this is to create an array of the content control tags you want to clear and then use the built-in method to find them. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.selectcontentcontrolsbytag and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.selectcontentcontrolsbytitle
Sub ClearCCs_Contents()
    Dim cc As ContentControl, index As Long
    Dim ccList As Variant: ccList = Array("Section11", "Section23", "Section45", "Section24", "AppleID01")
    For index = LBound(ccList) To UBound(ccList)
        For Each cc In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag(ccList(index))
            'For Each cc In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(ccList(index))
            With cc.Range
                If .Tables.count > 0 Then .Tables(1).Delete Else .Text = ""
            End With
        Next cc
    Next index
End Sub


Appreciated. this solves the problem.

how about if the CC.range is not text but a table (from excel as currentregion)?

@Muhtar - see edited code.  This is the type of really simple edit you should be able to make yourself. You have access to all the tools in the VB editor - IntelliSense, the Object Browser, and online documentation.
